# producer consumer using queue in java

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

i implemented producer consumer problem, but id dont see why my program stop consuming even though producer produces please help me in finding bug and also fix.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class producerConsumer {
    private Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    private Random random = new Random();

    private synchronized void addData(int data) {
        while(queue.size()>=10) ;
        queue.add(data);
    }

    private synchronized int takeData() {
        while(queue.size()<=0) ;
        return queue.poll();
    }

    private void producer() {
        int data;
        while(true) {
            data=random.nextInt(100);
            addData(data);
            System.out.println("the producer produced :"+data);
        }
    }

    private void consumer() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                if(random.nextInt(10)==0) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("The consumed value:"+takeData()+";queue size is "+queue.size());
                }
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        producerConsumer pc = new producerConsumer();
        pc.process();
    }

    public void process() {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                producer();
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                consumer();
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you working in an IDE? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: You have ; after while in both addData() and takeData(). After all how can you poll an element from a queue when its size is lower than 0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put your while loops inside a synchronized method, the consumer will never release the lock. Put some wait()/notify() logic inside. Or use some standard synchronized queue implementation.

The following should work better:

```
private synchronized void addData(int data) {
    while(queue.size()>=10) wait(); //wait() will temporarily release lock
    queue.add(data);
    notifyAll();
}

private synchronized int takeData() {
    while(queue.size()<=0) wait(); //wait() will temporarily release lock
    int poll = queue.poll();
    notifyAll();
    return poll;
}
```

Comment: the example is not correct because wait throw InterruptedException.but the wait/notify() is working...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

@greyfairer's answer looks to be correct but for posterity I'd recommend that you look at the the `ExecutorService` classes which take care of most of your code for you including the queuing of jobs and the signaling between the producer and consumer.  You might be doing this as an exercise but if not, here's a [good tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

What is missing from the standard `ExecutorService` is limiting the number of outstanding jobs so the producer doesn't overwhelm memory by queuing up too many jobs.  For that you need to do a bounded queue and use the `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

Fore more details, see this answer: [Process Large File for HTTP Calls in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184005/process-large-file-for-http-calls-in-java/13184026#13184026)