# Multithread - OutOfMemory

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, hashmap

I am using an `ThreadPoolExecutor` with 5 active threads, number of tasks is huge 20,000.
The queue is filled up (`pool.execute(new WorkingThreadTask())`) with instances of a `Runnable` tasks almost immediately.

Each `WorkingThreadTask` has a `HashMap`:

```
Map<Integer, HashMap<Integer, String>> themap ;
```

each map can have up to 2000 items, and each sub-map has 5 items.  There is also a shared `BlockingQueue`.

When process is running I am getting out of memory.  I'm running with: `(32bit -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m)`

How can I handle this problem?  I don't think I have leaks in hashmap...  When the thread is finished hashmap is cleaned right?

**Update:**

After running a profiler and checking the memory, the biggest hit is:

```
byte[] 2,516,024 hits, 918 MB
```

I don't know from where it's called or used.

```
Name    Instance count  Size (bytes)
byte[ ] 2519560 918117496
oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTCItem    2515402 120739296
char[ ] 357882  15549280
java.lang.String    9677    232248
int[ ]  2128    110976
short[ ]    2097    150024
java.lang.Class 1537    635704
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync    1489    35736
java.util.Hashtable$Entry   1417    34008
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry[ ] 1376    22312
java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment  1376    44032
java.lang.Object[ ] 1279    60216
java.util.TreeMap$Entry 828 26496
oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBItem[ ]  802 10419712
oracle.jdbc.ttc7.v8TTIoac   732 52704
```

Comment: Try profiling the memory to see what is eating it. The `HashMap`s should get GC'd, but only if nothing retains a reference to them afterwards.

Comment: If hashmap is not shared how can it retain a refernece?

Comment: I don't know your code. A reference could be passed to somewhere else with results from the tasks for example. But it can be something completely different and a memory profile will tell you what the program filled the memory with.

Comment: 20,000 runnables x 2,000 map items x 5 submaps = 200,000,000 objects...

Comment: Igor, 200,000,000 bu each tread handles only 2000*5 and after it finshes hashmap should be cleaned

Comment: try using WeakHashMap if objects added to it are not retained.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the inner map but I suspect the problem is that you are creating a large number of tasks that is filling memory.  You should be using a bounded task queue and limit the job producer.

Take a look at my answer here: [Process Large File for HTTP Calls in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184005/process-large-file-for-http-calls-in-java/13184026#13184026)

To summarize it, you should create your own bounded queue and then use a `RejectedExecutionHandler` to block the producer until there is space in the queue.  Something like:

```
final BlockingQueue<WorkingThreadTask> queue =
    new ArrayBlockingQueue<WorkingThreadTask>(100);
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool =
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
// we need our RejectedExecutionHandler to block if the queue is full
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
       @Override
       public void rejectedExecution(WorkingThreadTask task,
             ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
           try {
                // this will block the producer until there's room in the queue
                executor.getQueue().put(task);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RejectedExecutionException(
                   "Unexpected InterruptedException", e);
           }
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

> I don't think I have leeks in hashmap... when thread is finished hashmap is cleaned right?

You might consider aggressively calling `clear()` on the work `HashMap` and other collections when the task completes. Although they should be reaped by the GC eventually, giving the GC some help may solve your problem if you have limited memory.

If this doesn't work, a profiler is the way to go to help you identify where the memory is being held.

**Edit:**

After looking at the profiler output, the `byte[]` is interesting.  Typically this indicates some sort of serialization or other IO.  You may also be storing blobs in a database.  The `oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTCItem` is *very* interesting however.  That indicates to me that you are not closing a database connection somewhere.  Make sure to use proper try/finally blocks to close your connections.

Comment: Same issue even if ArrayBlockingQueue size is 5

Comment: I think the reason is that the hashmap in completed task is not getting cleared.

Comment: One thing to do @markiz is to aggressively call clear on the work `HashMap` and other collections.  Although they should be reaped by the GC eventually, giving the GC some help may solve your problem.  Otherwise a profiler is the way to go.

Comment: You doing any serialization @markiz? The `byte[]` is interesting.  Are you closing your database connections?

Comment: I am reusing connections, one of the issues that I've found that I  didn't close RecordSet and PreparedStatement after usage. Connection was reused but recordset and PreparedStatement  were not reused but recreated without closing the previous.

Comment: Yeah that's bad.  How much memory was that accounting for @markiz?  Always use try/finally blocks with those.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap carries quite a lot of overhead in terms of memory usage..... it carries about 36 bytes minimum per entry, plus the size of the key/value itself - each will be at least 32 bytes (I think that's about the typical value for 32-bit sun JVM).... doing some quick math:

```
20,000 tasks, each with map with 2000 entry hashmap. The value in the map is another map with 5 entries.
->  5-entry map is 1* Map + 5* Map.Object entries + 5*keys + 5*values = 16 objects at 32 bytes => 512 bytes per sub-map.
->  2000 entry map is 1* Map, 2000*Map.Object + 2000 keys + 2000 submaps (each is 512 bytes) => 2000*(512+32+32) + 32 => 1.1MB
->  20,000 tasks, each of 1.1MB -> 23GB
```

So, your overall footprint is 23GB.

The logical solution is to restrict the depth of your blocking queue feeding the ExecutorService, and only create enough child tasks to keep it busy..... set a limit of about 64 entries in the queue, and then you will never have more than 64 + 5 tasks instantiated at one time. When wpace comes available in the executor's queue, you can create and add another task.

Comment: but why? Each task handles 200 * 5 items.
5 threads run in same time.
after task is finished all it's data is cleaned. not?

Comment: it depends on how many tasks are queued up waiting to execute. Also, you will probably have Future objects needing to be processed as well.

Comment: if task is waiting, it's HM is empty. it's getting filled only when it runs

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the efficiency by not adding so many tasks ahead of what is being processed.  Try checking the queue and only adding to it if there is less than 1000 entries.

You can also make the data structures more efficient. A Map with an Integer key can often be reduced to an array of some kind.

Lastly, 1 GB isn't that much these days.  My mobile phone has 2 GB.  If you are going to process large amount of data, I suggest getting a machine with 32-64 GB of memory and a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: For your first point I tried the suggested by Gray, without success.

I will make another strucute if this helps...

Regarding memory, it will be ran on 64bit machine but for now I am working and testing on 32.

Comment: I run a ton of medium to large data processing on 4gb or less machines.  Certainly 64-bit is always a good idea but sounds to me that Peter is spoiled with his 32+gb of core. ;-)

Comment: @Gray I used to have a 256 GB for work, but now I make do with 32 GB. I have a 480 GB PCI SSD so running out of memory is much of a performance hit. BTW 32 GB gamer memory + 480 GB PCI SSD < £1000, it's not big money.

Comment: Oh yes, a SSD is the first requirement but 32gb is still a lot of memory for me.  :-)  I've been a laptop guy for a while now and they usually just don't have slot space or the chip density to do it.  Oh, and I'm cheap.  Then again, I'm not doing the high performance fu that you are.  Cheers.

Comment: @Gray you can buy 32 GB for £210. I have an Ultrabook with 8 GB & 256GB SSD and it's enough for what I do on it.  My next machine will have 64 GB.  BTW When I bought my son a computer for his 8th birthday, I bought it with 8 GB as 4 GB would have only saved £20.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, you can see the results of profiler in my post

Answer (score 0):

From the large `byte[]`s, I'd suspect IO related issues (unless you are handling video/audio or something).

Things to look at:

- DB: Are you trying to read large amount of stuff at once? You can
  e.g. use a cursor to not do that
- File/Network: Are you trying to read large amounts of stuff from file/network at once? You should "propagate the load" to whatever is reading and regulate the rate of read.

**UPDATE**: OK, so you are using a cursor to read from DB. Now you need to make sure that the reading from the cursor only progresses as you finish stuff (aka "propagate the load"). To do this, use a thread pool like this:

```
 BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(queueSize);
 ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    threadNum,
                    threadNum,
                    1000,
                    TimeUnit.HOURS,
                    queue,
                    new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

Now when you post to this service from your code which reads from the DB, it will block when the queue is full (the calling thread is used to run tasks and hence blocks).

Comment: Yes I am reading a lot of DB data. I am using a cursor ResultSet.next