# How to throttle method invocations to allow threads to complete

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I currently have the following setup. I am getting out fo memory exceptions after it runs for a little while; I suspect the for loop in main is causing too much of a backup method calls. What is the best way to throttle the calls if I don't wish to increase the thread pool size?

```
public class ManagedThreads {
   private final static ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

   public static void myMethod(final int i) {
      ex.execute(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             // method body  using i
         }
      });
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
         myMethod(i);
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

I meant to show that I am passing in the index for the loop to the runnables.

Comment: It's running out of memory because it's creating millions of `Runnable` objects and storing them in the executor queue faster than they can be executed. The only way to get around this is to slow down your for loop somehow. For example you can have `myMethod` keep track of how many runnables have yet to be executed and if it is above some number then block until it falls below that number.

Comment: the throttling is highly dependent on the `method body`. you might not need those billions of runnables. depending on the `method body` you might only need to alter the logic to support throttling.

Comment: @csoroiu added information about method body. I guess the main thing was that I use the index from the for loop in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ten threads so add ten jobs and you will never run out of memory trying to schedule them.

e.g.

```
public class ManagedThreads {
   private final static ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

   public static void myMethod(final int i) {
      ex.execute(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             // do every tenth task.
             for(int j = i; j < 1000000000; j += 10) {
                 // method body
             }
         }
      });
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
         myMethod(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting out fo memory exceptions after it runs for a little while; I suspect the for loop in main is causing too much of a backup method calls. What is the best way to throttle the calls if I don't wish to increase the thread pool size?

This is a FAQ.  See my answer here: [Process Large File for HTTP Calls in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184005/process-large-file-for-http-calls-in-java/13184026#13184026)

You need to define your own bounded job queue and then define a `RejectedExecutionHandler`.  The following code will block when it tries to add more than 100 jobs to the job queue.

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100);
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool =
     new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
// we need our RejectedExecutionHandler to block if the queue is full
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
       @Override
       public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
           try {
                // this will block the producer until there's room in the queue
                executor.getQueue().put(r);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RejectedExecutionException(
                   "Unexpected InterruptedException", e);
           }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i would go with this (it will allow each worker to perform same amount of work in terms of cpu clocks)

```
    private final static ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    final static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static void myMethod(final int i) {
       ex.execute(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              while (counter.getAndIncrement() < 1000000000) {
                  //method body
              }
          }
       });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
          myMethod(i);
    }
 }
```

or do increments of 10 in each worker as Peter suggested. Saves a lot of objects and processing speed is high.