# passing diffrenet runnables or messages to a single predefined thread in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

In my splash screen i send two different requests to my server and i want to wait for the results then parse them and after that go to my main activity. i am using volley and i want to parse two results in mThread, and after making sure that i successfully have all i need, i call startActivity and .... so my problem is how can i send two different runnables to mThread or how can i send my string responses to my mThread to parse it and after last runnable or message call another activity. and also how can i call finish method at the end ? i consider this option but get nowhere:

using handler, but if i want to use handler as you know each handler is assigned to the thread that created it so creating handler in onCreate method is wrong because i want to make my thread go to sleep if the requests have not received yet and also do not want to do my computation on the main thread.

and the code that i do not know how to solve it is :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // ....
  mThread = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            Log.i("Recieved String",response);
       if( two runnable completed){

            Intent i = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

          how to call finish()?

       }
     }

    };

 //... 

            MyVolleyRequest Request1 = new MyVolleyRequest(URL1, 
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // sending response to mThread
                // or sending runnable to mThread
            }
        }, 

        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {                               

            }
        });


           MyVolleyRequest Request2 = new MyVolleyRequest(URL2, 
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // sending response to mThread
                // or sending runnable to mThread
            }
        }, 

        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {                               

            }
        });

        SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(SplashActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(Request1);
        SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(SplashActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(Request2);
```

I will appreciate any practical and clean solution !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Executor Framework, with it you can create a thread pool containing one Thread. The Thread is going to wait for Tasks (Runnables) to execute. And is going to execute them one by one.

```
private ExecutorService executorService;    
executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

send Tasks this way:

```
executorService.execute(new YourRunnable());
```

You could also create a n-sized thread pool using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)` if you wanted to execute several task concurrently. Or submit a `Callable` if you need a value to be returned. Here's a little [introduction](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#threadpools).

There is also the [GuavaLibrary](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) to implement callbacks called when the tasks finish.

Comment: Thank you very much , but one question and how can i detect that i have finished two tasks, and how can i call finsh() at the end of my last task, i do not know what is my last task and also how can i call finish on the another thread?

Comment: A way to do it, is to pass a handler (created in the main thread) to the Runnable `executorService.execute(new Runnable(new Handler())`. Inside of Runnable.run() method, when you finish your operations, use the `handler.post()` to send another runnable to the main thread's message queue. `handler.post(new Runnable() {public void run() { //executes in the main thread }});`

Comment: what is my last task ? how can i detect it to pass runnable?

Comment: You can simply increment a counter with the handler.post(). or implement instead a `ThreadPoolExecutor` which has methods to get the active or completed tasks. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18985768/2017375

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`CountDownLatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) starting at a count of 2. Your mThread calls the `await()` method and both HTTP handlers each call `countDown()` after they delivered their part of the result.

Comment: thank you but how can i pass two runnables to mThread? i want to execute them in the mThread when they are received !!